# Is there a strings or language file I can add to an Ionic project?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

How can I make a language/string file and reference it in the HTML and code base?
It would help reduce spelling errors, make it easy to change in one place, and easier to translate.
Kind of like android studio's strings.xml.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you want to do? 
Detail a little more the functionality you expect.

Comment: What's the javascript framework that you're using ? is it angular ?

Comment: Sorry, I am using angular. I would like a central place to keep strings and reference them in titles, labels, components, etc. It would be for potentially translation later. Like having a translator go through only one file. And it would be used for being able to change a word in only place rather than changing it everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the javascript framework that you're using behind the ionic-framework.

In case of angular , you can consider the [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) , once you configure it , you can put your strings inside a json file , and you'll be using the keys to match the translations/full-text.

Comment: This is more or less what I was looking for, thank you. 
Although, configuring it has been a pain..